# What do you call someone who always makes the conversation about themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, epithet-requests

For example, let's say I am starting a story about something that happened to me, and in the middle of the story, they start like "oh, the same thing happened to me when I was..." and start to tell their story. They don't even remember I was in a middle of my story.

Is there a single word for that?
They are all not narcissistic but close.

Comment: ***Narcissists*** works for me. The first result from feeding your question text into a Google search is [*4 Signs You're Talking To A **Conversational Narcissist***.](https://www.mindbodygreen.com/articles/conversational-narcissist-definition-and-signs#:~:text=A%20conversational%20narcissist%20is%20someone,other%20people%20have%20to%20say.&text=This%20is%20typically%20the%20case%20with%20conversational%20narcissism.)

Comment: I don't why this has closed. This is not a duplicate question if you have read the file question

Comment: I didn't vote to close as a duplicate. I just think that the English language as such doesn't have a specific term for what you seek. But as per my link above, *The term “**conversational narcissist**” was coined by sociologist Charles Derber who describes **the trait of consistently turning a conversation back to yourself**.* The fact that a sociologist felt it necessary to coin that term strongly implies there wasn't any pre-existing expression. And I can't see why you don't think it suitable, since that definition seems to exactly match your context.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't talking to you, I was talking to whoever cote to close this. But yeah you are right, there is no any exact word for that. Also, the narcissist doesn't work because it's not exactly the word, maybe the explanation was bad

Comment: I still don't understand why you keep saying "narcissist doesn't work". It's easily understood even on first encounter, *and* it's got some traction. I like this one from 2010... [*"Well I've been talking long enough about me , so what do **you** think of me?" typifies the conversational narcissist*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22been+talking+long+enough+about+me%22+%22conversational+narcissist%22)